# Ajax call on page load in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I am new to ember js technology. I am facing some issues in my ember application. I have some files in my ember application as below(partial code is given below):-

**sample.hbs**

```
    <div>
    <div>
    {{text-field id="countryid" type="text"}}
    </div>
    {{state-component model=model}}
    </div>
```

**state-component.hbs**

```
    {{#if isFlag}}
    <div>
    {{text-field id="stateid" type="text"}}
    </div>
    {{else}}
    {{/if}}
```

**state-component.js**

```
    var flag;
    export default Ember.Component.extend({
    isFlag: Ember.computed('flag', function() {
    flag = this.get('model').get('flag');
    return Ember.isEqual(flag, 'true');
})
    })
```

**sample.js**

```
    export default Ember.Route.extend({ 
    model(){
    return info.create({"flag": ""})
    }});

    afterModel(){
    Ember.$.ajax({    
    url: `${ENV.host}/retrieveInfo`,
    type: 'POST',
    data: `id=geoid`,
    success: (data) => {
      this.modelFor('sample').setProperties({ 
          "flag": data.flag
      });
    }
    }
```

Here on page load retrieveInfo ajax call happens & the flag is returned from the webservice call. Based on flag value, i.e. if true then only I have to display state textbox. But since page renders first and next ajax call happens I do not have flag value on page load. i.e. When state-component gets rendered, it doesn't contain flag value. I have moved the ajax call in different events like willRender(), didRender(). But it didn't help. Could someone give solution? Where I can put the ajax call so that I can get the flag value in my state-component?

Comment: Please change the question title to a better one.

Comment: I have changed my question so that you would be able understand. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Always ask question with code what you have tried. if possible include [ember-twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com) reproduction.By the way you cant create component named `component1` since it should contain `-`.

Give a good read on official [ember-guides](http://guides.emberjs.com)

Define it in model hook of the sample route and it will be available in settings.hbs.

```
model(){
  return Ember.$.getJSON('url');
}
```

You can send model to `my-component`and it will be accessible in `my-component`.

```
{{my-component model=model }}
```